# Angular - Filter an array

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering how I can filter an array to show only results if a property in the array is empty. I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
<tr ng-repeat="performanceOrder in performanceOrders | filter: salesId.length === 0">
```

I only want to show results if `salesId` is empty, is this possible?

### Edit

`salesId` is a property of `performanceOrder`

```
performanceOrder: {
    salesId: "S273626",
    status: "Open",
    ...
}
```

Comment: define `empty` , undefined or other?

Comment: Try == instead of ===, it might be comparing a string to an int.

Comment: @charlietfl not undefined, just an empty string, so ""

Answer (score 1):

With [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow):

```
<tr ng-show="!salesId.length" ng-repeat="performanceOrder in performanceOrders">
```

With [ngIf](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf):

```
<tr ng-if="!salesId.length" ng-repeat="performanceOrder in performanceOrders">
```

Comment: show and filter do different things...can't get a filter count for example with this approach

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure where salesId comes from. It doesn't look like as a part of performanceOrders, so I figured if salesId is empty ng-repeat shouldn't run at all.

Comment: @OlivérKovács salesId is a property on a performanceOrder, so I don't think ng-show and ng-if apply, as it needs to be a filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function inside the filter like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="performanceOrder in performanceOrders | filter: myFilter()>
```

Then, in your corresponding controller, you can do something like:

```
$scope.myFilter = function (val) {
  return val.salesId.length === 0;
}
```

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Remove `()` from `myFilter()`.